# React Hook "useStyles" is called in function which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per the title, I am getting the following error message when implementing Material UI with React.

> React Hook "useStyles" is called in function "appBar" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I have reviewed the rules of hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and I am not sure what I have missed. Any assistance rendered would be appreciated.

Here is my source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
  }),
);

export default function appBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try renaming `appBar` to `AppBar`, or something in PascalCase.

Comment: Components have to be named with Pascal case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try renaming your component with [PascalCase](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase).

[eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) thinks that your function component is *not a function component* because it doesn't start with a capital letter.

Note: the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) state that *user-defined components must be capitalized before their use in JSX* to avoid being treated as HTML elements.

In the example below I've named the component `AppBarWrapper` because the name `AppBar` is already being used by the component imported from `@material-ui/core/AppBar`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
  }),
);

export default function AppBarWrapper() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First install:

```
npm install @material-ui/styles
```

Second:  read documentation

> "
> Getting started
> There are 3 possible APIs you can use to generate and apply styles, however they all share the same underlying logic."

Hook API

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can add a link to the documentation.