# Call of hooks is inside of functional component give error Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have component language for translations

```
const Language = (props: IOwnProps) => {
    // error is in next line for useSelector 
    const language = useSelector(
        (state: IState) => state.currentLang
    );
    
    return getTranslations(
        props.languageString
    );
};
```

in form I have validation using formik

```
const validationSchema = () => {
    const requiredFirstName = Language({
        languageString: firstNameRequired,
    });
    return yup.object({
        firstName: yup
            .string()
            .required(requiredFirstName)
    });
};
```

here is form component

```
const UserForm = ({
    userData: userData
    setErrorIndex,
}: UserFormProps) => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            userData: userData.firstName,
        },
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            const playerDataLocal = {
                firstName: values.firstName,
            };
            handleSubmit(playerDataLocal);
        },
    });

    return (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                label="First Name *"
                defaultValue={formik.values.firstName}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                error={formik.touched.firstName && Boolean(formik.errors.firstName)}
                helperText={formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName}
                fullWidth
            />
        </form>
    );
};
export default UserForm;
```

in validation schema line with Language give an error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Call of `Language` is from `validationSchema` that is a functional component
call stack of error is in line of `useSelector` from `Language`
call of `validationSchema` is inside of 'useFormik' can be this the issue?
any ideas?

Comment: You have to name your hooks with prefix `use`, e.g. `useLanguage` and `useValidationSchema`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795387/5385381

Comment: Looks lik `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` thinks you are breaking the rules of hooks because `validationSchema` doesn't begin with a capital letter or the `use` prefix.

Comment: or call that `useSelector` in parent component `UserForm` and forward it as prop - and you don't have to rename with `use`

Comment: `Language` doesn’t look like a component?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Language is a component

Comment: @fast-reflexes renamed both useLanguage and useValidationSchema, the error is the same. one think here is when useFormik is called validationSchema can't be renamed, and I call like this: validationSchema: useValidationSchema,

Comment: @Alex it doesn’t look like it since components are supposed to either return another component or jsx.

Comment: @evolutionxbox hmm, yeah, there is no jsx in return, Language return a string, but it has functional component structure

Comment: @evolutionxbox can be this the issue?

Comment: In react a component is a function which returns another component or jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `validationSchema` is not a React component. You can only use hooks inside of either a functional component or another hook and since `validationSchema` returns something other than JSX or another component it is not classed as either (see [React docs for Hook Rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)).

You will probably want to move your hook call up inside `UserForm` and then pass the result into `validationSchema` as an argument.

Comment: thx for your answer, it works when is inside of UserForm, but now UserForm is very big component :)

Comment: It's unfortunately inevitable that components with lots of hooks get large and can't be split. I'me currently working in a component 1200 lines long...

Comment: You can call hooks from other hooks too, an important details that needs to be clear.

Comment: @fast-reflexes Do you have a link to the docs where it says that? I can't find the reference but will update my answer to include if I get it

Comment: @Tom Besides having done it a million times: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions. I'd say that's where the power of custom hooks lie. Otherwise we could just make it a regular function. OP even calls another hook in `Language`, which is really a hook with an incorrect name (or perhaps it IS a React component, impossible to see from context).

Comment: @fast-reflexes Thanks I have updated the answer. I actually didn't know you could put hooks inside hooks so I've learnt something new today too!